# $\lim_n \frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sup_{x\in[x_{k-1},x_k]}f$, $\lim_n \frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\inf_{x\in[x_{k-1},x_k]}f$ and Darboux integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let us use the notation $\overline{\int_a^b}f(x)dx$ for the [Darboux upper integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral#Darboux_integrals) of $f$ and $\underline{\int_a^b}f(x)dx$ for the lower one.

Let us construct a partition of $[a,b]$ into $n$ intervals $[x_{k-1},x_k]$ defined by $x_k=a+k(b-a)/n$ and les us consider the corresponding Darboux sums$$\Delta_n=\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sup_{x\in[x_{k-1},x_k]}f(x),\quad \delta_n=\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\inf_{x\in[x_{k-1},x_k]}f(x).$$

It is clear, by taking the definitions of $\sup$ and $\inf$, and the fact that such partitions are subsets of all partitions of $[a,b]$ into countably many closed intervals, into account, that $\lim_n\Delta_n\geq\overline{\int_a^b}f(x)dx$ and $\lim_n\delta_n\leq \underline{\int_a^b}f(x)dx$.

I wonder whether, analogously to [what happens](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980946/darboux-integrals-with-bisected-partition) for partitions into $m^n$ intervals with $m\ge 2$, $m\in\mathbb{N}$, it is true that $\lim_n\Delta_n=\overline{\int_a^b}f(x)dx$ and $\lim_n\delta_n= \underline{\int_a^b}f(x)dx$. I have not been able to prove it and suspect that it is not true, but I would like to ask whether the equalities $\lim_n\Delta_n=\overline{\int_a^b}f(x)dx$ and $\lim_n\delta_n= \underline{\int_a^b}f(x)dx$ are true and, if they are, how it can be proved. I thank anybody for any answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true !

Read [D.Brannan *A First Course in Mathematical Analysis* (2006)](https://books.google.it/books?id=N8bL9lQUGJgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=brannan+mathematical+analysis&hl=it&sa=X&ei=G4EOVdSkCcm5UZe9gMAO&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=brannan%20mathematical%20analysis&f=false) pp. 269-272 .

Restate cleverly Theorem 7 (a) removing the integrability assumption and substituting $\,\int_a^b f\,$ with $\,\underline{\int_a^b}f$ and $\,\overline{\int_a^b}f$ respectively. On p. 271, $\,I\,$ becomes $\,\overline{\int_a^b}f$.

So your statement is proved for every sequence of partitions with the mesh converging to zero.

Comment: ...and by taking into account that, with the notation of lemma 3, $L(f,P')\le L(f,P)+N(M-m)\delta$, we analogously get that $\underline{\int_a^b}f\ge L(f,P_n)\ge L(f,P_n'-\frac{1}{n})\ge L(f,Q_n)-\frac{1}{n}>\underline{\int_a^b}f-\frac{2}{n}$. I $\infty$-ly thank you!